# Failed to resolve com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:0.3.0

Tags: android, video, video-capture

I am using https://github.com/afollestad/material-camera.

As i do add compile 'com.afollestad:material-camera:0.4.4'

I giving me error:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure to add those lines to your gradle file

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
}
```